# Changing colour of header background on scroll

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll, scrolltop

I'm trying to change the background colour of the header for my WordPress site on scroll. I am using the scrollTop function to achieve this but for whatever reason the value is currently being returned as a function. Using the below code to the log the scroll position to the console I am getting this:

```
ƒ (e){return $(this,function(e,t,n){var r;if(x(e)?r=e:9===e.nodeType&&(r=e.defaultView),void 0===n)return r?r[i]:e[t];r?r.scrollTo(o?r.pageXOffset:n,o?n:r.pageYOffset):e[t]=n},t,e,arguments.length)}
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    });
});
```

As the scroll position isn't being returned as a value I can't use it to write the logic for my header. From what I've seen scrollTop should initially log to the console 0, then increase as the window scrolls. I was wondering if anyone else had run into the same issue.

Comment: How should it work? You have scrolled and the title color should change, but when you scroll back up the title color will be the default. So it must be?

Comment: Yeah essentially. If scrollTop > 0 change background colour, otherwise background default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you an example of setting the title color using the `addClass()` method when scrolling. When the scrolling position is returned, the class with the desired color is removed - `removeClass()`:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
   $("p").addClass("color_scroll");
} else {
   $("p").removeClass("color_scroll");
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $("p").addClass("color_scroll");
    } else {
      $("p").removeClass("color_scroll");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
}

p {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

p.color_scroll {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Title</p>
```